# Setting the Datacontext of a dynamically created control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl (Map) that contains a Canvas control. I am dynamically adding a control (Gate) to this canvas from the code behind.

I want the Gate objects DataContext to be the "Gate" property of the Map's DataContext. This is being done in the code behind.

```
 Binding dataContextBinding = new Binding();
        dataContextBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self);
        dataContextBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("DataContext.SelectedLevelModule.Gate");
        dataContextBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        dataContextBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(gate, DataContextProperty, dataContextBinding);
```

After this block of code runs, the gate.DateContext is null...
Any ways this can be done? Drawing a blank..
Thanks
Harold

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the property path to `DataContext.SelectedLevelModule.Gate`. You are then assigning the binding to the `DataContextProperty`. I think what is happening is that the path is now `gate.DataContext.DataContext.SelectedLevelModule.Gate`.

Try removing DataContext from your `PropertyPath` and see if that fixes it. You are already assigning it to the DataContext, you should not have to specify it in the Path.

```
var dataContextBinding = new Binding();
dataContextBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedLevelModule.Gate");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(gate, DataContextProperty, dataContextBinding);
```